# How can I display that an event is full on a Drupal View?

Tags: civievent

Currently a user needs to click through to an Event info page before they know if it is full or not.

Is there a way to take this information:

> "This event is currently full."

and display it in a Drupal View/ Pane?

Answer (score 5):

One approach would be to use the [views_php](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) module to embed a civicrm_api3 call to find out if the event is full, then print the result into the view. E.g.

```
$event = civicrm_api3('Event', 'getsingle', array('return' => 'is_full', 'id' => $row->id));
if (!empty($event['is_full']) {
  print "Event is full";
}
```

Comment: You can get the is_full value from the event get api call and requesting "return.is_full" in the params

Comment: Two years later is still one of the best solutions?

Answer (score 4):

We have been using the module "views conditional" to do that. Here's how it works:

1. install and enable the module "Views Conditional"
2. enable the relationship *Event -> Participant* in the view
3. activate aggregation in the view in order to count the number of
   participants (hide it if necessary)
4. add the field to the view: *(Event -> Participant) COUNT(CiviCRM
   Participants: Participant ID)* (hide it if necessary)
5. add the field to the view: *CiviCRM Events: Event Max-Participants*
6. add a global field (math expression) to the view and calculate the
   remaining places. The math expression could look like this (but
   depends on the name of your fields: [max_participants] - [id_1]
7. add a views conditional field and define it similar to this: Views: *Views
   Conditional (If expression is Less than 1, output FULLY BOOKED, else
   output REGISTRATION AVAILABLE)* (also see screenshot)

Be aware that this approach is also kind of a workaround and has some shortcomings. For example, the aggregation function would also count cancelled participants. You could set a filter but it may have undesired results on your view (such as not showing events without a registration).

Nevertheless, the views conditional module in combination with the aggregate function may open up new possibilities for you. Just make sure to test properly before productive use.

Answer (score 3):

In the Drupal extension [CiviCRM Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity) [7.x-2.0-beta9 release](https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity/releases/7.x-2.0-beta9) there is a new feature that allows to check if an event is full as view extra.

> CiviCRM Views Extras -- Added Views field handler for CiviCRM Events -
>   Event is Full - True if event is full false otherwise

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. You can create your own views based upon the CiviCRM event data what you need to do is probably build a check in your view which compares the number of registered people of the number of available places.

Answer (score 2):

Just had to set this up, and the combo of civicrm entity 2.1 and views conditional works really well.

Make a view of civicrm event type. Add the "event is full" field and then make the views conditional based on whether event is full is 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1):

We experience the same challenge. I see a solution with the views_php module but that is not a recommended module. Another way would be to use a custom event field that has the number of registered people (filled after every registration by a custom extension). That field would be available in the views module. But easier would be if there was a way provided by civicrm core to retrieve the number of registered people in a view. That field I believe is not available (yet).